# Revving up engine gives more power to steering

Tags: manual-transmission, preventive-maintenance, maruti

I'm from India and I drive a manual Petrol Maruti Suzuki Baleno. The car handles kind of well and it's been only since I have bought it and has driven for around 10,000 km.

Yesterday, I accidentally pushed on the accelerator thinking it was the brake, but the car was in neutral so it didn't move forward but it revved to around 6k. Afterward, when I started driving the car I started to notice that the steering had become way more responsive, the gears were changing really smoothly and the car had a noticeable increase in power.

This has happened previously too, but I don't try it since I am afraid it would wear out the car. There is a marked increase in the smoothness of the drive too.

I am a newbie driver so, when some experienced drivers take my car for a ride and they return it, the smoothness and the power come back. But after I drive for a while the car returns back to the less responsive state.

I upshift at around 2k rev, and do not downshift gears even when the rev is at 1.5k is this causing the issue ?

Comment: When the engine spinning faster, the power steering will be more responsive. Some cars power steering pumps struggle at idle. However 1500 rpm should be fast enough you shouldn't notice any issue. Also, given your engine and vehicle size, I'd probably shift at around 2700 instead of 2000, and generally keep the rpm's above 1800 when under any load, but that's a matter of personal opinion and shouldn't affect your power steering noticeably.

Comment: I would give a check to the power steering fluid and belt, it is possible that the belt is slipping on low rpm and when it gets on higher rpm the momentum makes the pump go with a normal speed.